# When ever the node server is refreshed then the axios data is sended to the server from react without a click of button or anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

When I send request from frontend (react) to backend (node) through axios it does get the data in the server but when i refresh the server the same data is sent to the backend on the starting.

If it doesn't make any sense then just see the images and code below.

**code of button click function in react**

```
const BtnClickHandler = (item) => {   
    console.log(item);

    if(localStorage.getItem('token')){    
        axios.post(
            "http://localhost:5050/cartAdd",
            {
                data: {
                    cartArray: item,
                },
            },
            // {
            //   headers: {
            //     Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
            //   },
            // }
        ).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
 
        props.AddItemToCart(item)
    }else{
        alert('Please Login Fist to Add the food items into the cart');
        props.history.push('/');
    }
};
```

**The controller code of node**

```
exports.PostCartAdd = (req, res, next) => {
    var cartItems = req.body.data.cartArray 
    console.log(cartItems);
}
```

The image of server log before sever is refreshed:

[image]

The image of server log after the server is refreshed:

[image]

So as you see the data which comes in the request before server refreshes, the same data comes to the server after the server refreshes without any click in the frontend.

Comment: It's probably because your `BtnClickHandler` is defined as a constant which will be defined at the start of the server. Try simply defining this handler as a function.

Comment: can you give me a example?

Comment: @Jamie_D `BtnClickHandler` is declared as a function.